# How to get repeating roots in sympy?

Tags: python, math, sympy

```
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy.solvers import solveset

x = Symbol('x')
equation = x**2 - 2*x + 1
result = solveset(equation, x)
```

Here, `result` evaluates to `FiniteSet(1)`.

Since this is a quadratic equation, there must be 2 roots.

But also, since the two roots are the same (1 in this case), the result returns it only once.

For the purpose of solving linear recurrences, I need to know the repeated roots, and how many times did each one of them repeat.

How to do that?

Comment: Can you use `nroots` instead of `solveset`?  [Example using nroots](http://mattpap.github.io/scipy-2011-tutorial/html/summation.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it into a polynomial and then use the `roots` function, which will return a dictionary that has the roots as keys and the multiplicities as values, like so:

```
from sympy import roots
poly = equation.as_poly()
roots(poly)

# returns {1: 2}
```

Unlike `nroots`, this works with polynomials with symbolic coefficients as well:

```
from sympy.abc import a, b, c

poly = (a * x ** 2 - 2 * sqrt(a * c) * x + c).as_poly(x)
roots(poly, x)
# returns {sqrt(a*c)/a: 2}
```